# TensorFlow, Julia - Tensors and Floats

Tags: tensorflow, julia

Why can I convert a Float to a tensor, like this:

```
tensor = convert(TensorFlow.Tensor{Float32}, 0.05)
<Tensor Cast_8:1 shape=() dtype=Float32>
```

But not the Tensor to a Float. The following command:

```
convert(Float32, tensor)
```

return the following error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type TensorFlow.Tensor{Float32} to an object of type Float32
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Float32(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
```

How to use the value of a tensor in a variable or an array ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In TensorFlow (unlike in actual mathematics)
a `Tensor` is not really (only) a thing wrapping some numbers.
It is in a *symbolic value* in the computation graph, which can happen to hold constants, as in your case, but also variables and placeholders.  Thus, in general, `convert`ing back to a number doesn't make sense -- the variables and placeholders don't have concrete values at the time you just have defined them.

What you have to do instead is to `run` a tensor in a `Session`:

```
sess = Session(Graph())
run(sess, tensor)    # plus necessary initializers and placeholders
```

This will evaluate the computation graph up to the point where the value of `tensor` can be determined.  Just have a look at the [basic examples](https://malmaud.github.io/TensorFlow.jl/latest/basic_usage.html); all TensorFlow code is a repetition of this scheme: define the graph, and then run it in a session with the actual data provided for the placeholders and initial values.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Following that, is there a solution to use the floats in the tensor without convert it in float ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? You always need to `run` a `Tensor` to "get out" a float. That's not conversion, but evaluation.

Comment: In the example above, I would want to use the "0.05" in an array for example. If there are more values, copy them in an array.